# ANTLR does not match the pattens properly when there are similar patterns

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am using ANTLR to parse some queries.

Here is my ANTLR g4:

```
propTest
  : objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral    # propTestEqual
  | objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) 'wwww'              # propTestThlEqual
  ;

primitiveLiteral
  : orderableLiteral
  | BoolLiteral
  ;

primitiveLiteral
  : orderableLiteral
  ;

orderableLiteral
  : StringLiteral
  ;

StringLiteral
  : QUOTE ( ~['\\] | '\\\'' | '\\\\' )* QUOTE
  ;
```

The issue when I feed it with:

```
[network-traffic:src_port = '123]
```

I expect match happens on

```
: objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual
```

but it does not match anything but as soon as I remove

```
| objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) 'wwww'   # propTestThlEqual
```

then the match happens on

```
: objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual
```

Any idea what is going on?

** update

```
grammar STIXPattern;

pattern
  : observationExpressions EOF
  ;

observationExpressions
  : <assoc=left> observationExpressions FOLLOWEDBY observationExpressions #observationExpressionsFollowedBY
  | observationExpressionOr                                               #observationExpressionOr_
  ;

observationExpressionOr
  : <assoc=left> observationExpressionOr OR observationExpressionOr     #observationExpressionOred
  | observationExpressionAnd                                            #observationExpressionAnd_
  ;

observationExpressionAnd
  : <assoc=left> observationExpressionAnd AND observationExpressionAnd  #observationExpressionAnded
  | observationExpression                                               #observationExpression_
  ;

observationExpression
  : LBRACK comparisonExpression RBRACK        # observationExpressionSimple
  | LPAREN observationExpressions RPAREN      # observationExpressionCompound
  | observationExpression startStopQualifier  # observationExpressionStartStop
  | observationExpression withinQualifier     # observationExpressionWithin
  | observationExpression repeatedQualifier   # observationExpressionRepeated
  ;

comparisonExpression
  : <assoc=left> comparisonExpression OR comparisonExpression         #comparisonExpressionOred
  | comparisonExpressionAnd                                           #comparisonExpressionAnd_
  ;

comparisonExpressionAnd
  : <assoc=left> comparisonExpressionAnd AND comparisonExpressionAnd  #comparisonExpressionAnded
  | propTest                                                          #comparisonExpressionAndpropTest
  ;

propTest
  : objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual
  | objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) objectPathThl    # propTestThlEqual

  ;

startStopQualifier
  : START TimestampLiteral STOP TimestampLiteral
  ;

withinQualifier
  : WITHIN (IntPosLiteral|FloatPosLiteral) SECONDS
  ;

repeatedQualifier
  : REPEATS IntPosLiteral TIMES
  ;

objectPath
  : objectType COLON firstPathComponent objectPathComponent?
  ;

objectPathThl
  : varThlType DOT firstPathComponent objectPathComponent?
  ;

objectType
  : IdentifierWithoutHyphen
  | IdentifierWithHyphen
  ;

varThlType
  : IdentifierWithoutHyphen
  | IdentifierWithHyphen
  ;

firstPathComponent
  : IdentifierWithoutHyphen
  | StringLiteral
  ;

objectPathComponent
  : <assoc=left> objectPathComponent objectPathComponent  # pathStep
  | '.' (IdentifierWithoutHyphen | StringLiteral)         # keyPathStep
  | LBRACK (IntPosLiteral|IntNegLiteral|ASTERISK) RBRACK  # indexPathStep
  ;

setLiteral
  : LPAREN RPAREN
  | LPAREN primitiveLiteral (COMMA primitiveLiteral)* RPAREN
  ;

primitiveLiteral
  : orderableLiteral
  | BoolLiteral
  ;

orderableLiteral
  : IntPosLiteral
  | IntNegLiteral
  | FloatPosLiteral
  | FloatNegLiteral
  | StringLiteral
  | BinaryLiteral
  | HexLiteral
  | TimestampLiteral
  ;

IntNegLiteral :
  '-' ('0' | [1-9] [0-9]*)
  ;

IntPosLiteral :
  '+'? ('0' | [1-9] [0-9]*)
  ;

FloatNegLiteral :
  '-' [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
  ;

FloatPosLiteral :
  '+'? [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
  ;

HexLiteral :
  'h' QUOTE TwoHexDigits* QUOTE
  ;

BinaryLiteral :
  'b' QUOTE
  ( Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char )*
  ( (Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char )
  | (Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char ) '='
  | (Base64Char Base64Char ) '=='
  )
  QUOTE
  ;

StringLiteral :
  QUOTE ( ~['\\] | '\\\'' | '\\\\' )* QUOTE
  ;


BoolLiteral :
  TRUE | FALSE
  ;

TimestampLiteral :
  't' QUOTE
  [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] HYPHEN
  ( ('0' [1-9]) | ('1' [012]) ) HYPHEN
  ( ('0' [1-9]) | ([12] [0-9]) | ('3' [01]) )
  'T'
  ( ([01] [0-9]) | ('2' [0-3]) ) COLON
  [0-5] [0-9] COLON
  ([0-5] [0-9] | '60')
  (DOT [0-9]+)?
  'Z'
  QUOTE
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Keywords

AND:  'AND' ;
OR:  'OR' ;
NOT:  'NOT' ;
FOLLOWEDBY: 'FOLLOWEDBY';
LIKE:  'LIKE' ;
MATCHES:  'MATCHES' ;
ISSUPERSET:  'ISSUPERSET' ;
ISSUBSET: 'ISSUBSET' ;
LAST:  'LAST' ;
IN:  'IN' ;
START:  'START' ;
STOP:  'STOP' ;
SECONDS:  'SECONDS' ;
TRUE:  'true' ;
FALSE:  'false' ;
WITHIN:  'WITHIN' ;
REPEATS:  'REPEATS' ;
TIMES:  'TIMES' ;

// After keywords, so the lexer doesn't tokenize them as identifiers.
// Object types may have unquoted hyphens, but property names
// (in object paths) cannot.
IdentifierWithoutHyphen :
  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
  ;

IdentifierWithHyphen :
  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_-]*
  ;

EQ        :   '=' | '==';
NEQ       :   '!=' | '<>';
LT        :   '<';
LE        :   '<=';
GT        :   '>';
GE        :   '>=';

QUOTE     : '\'';
COLON     : ':' ;
DOT       : '.' ;
COMMA     : ',' ;
RPAREN    : ')' ;
LPAREN    : '(' ;
RBRACK    : ']' ;
LBRACK    : '[' ;
PLUS      : '+' ;
HYPHEN    : MINUS ;
MINUS     : '-' ;
POWER_OP  : '^' ;
DIVIDE    : '/' ;
ASTERISK  : '*';

fragment HexDigit: [A-Fa-f0-9];
fragment TwoHexDigits: HexDigit HexDigit;
fragment Base64Char: [A-Za-z0-9+/];

// Whitespace and comments
//
WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000B\u000C\u0085\u00a0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;

// Catch-all to prevent lexer from silently eating unusable characters.
InvalidCharacter
    : .
    ;
```

Comment: Please include all grammar rules needed to test your example input.

Comment: @BartKiers Please see my update. I added the full antlre part for this

Comment: @BartKiers I even tried to swap the orders of the lines hoping that would fix it but no luck. The above is just an example and in many other cases this : objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual is skipped as soon as the seconf rule is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not matching because you don't have the closing `'` on the `'123`

Here's your token stream (for your example) (I also included the error message)

```
[@0,0:0='[',<'['>,1:0]
[@1,1:15='network-traffic',<IdentifierWithHyphen>,1:1]
[@2,16:16=':',<':'>,1:16]
[@3,17:24='src_port',<IdentifierWithoutHyphen>,1:17]
[@4,26:26='=',<EQ>,1:26]
[@5,28:28=''',<'''>,1:28]
[@6,29:31='123',<IntPosLiteral>,1:29]
[@7,32:32=']',<']'>,1:32]
[@8,33:32='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:33]
line 1:28 no viable alternative at input 'network-traffic:src_port=''
```

It matches fine with the input `[network-traffic:src_port = '123']`

(I added your `| objectPath NOT? (EQ | NEQ) 'wwww' # propTestThlEqual1` alternative to popTest, and it matches the string above.

This is the tokenStream with the added `'`

```
[@0,0:0='[',<'['>,1:0]
[@1,1:15='network-traffic',<IdentifierWithHyphen>,1:1]
[@2,16:16=':',<':'>,1:16]
[@3,17:24='src_port',<IdentifierWithoutHyphen>,1:17]
[@4,26:26='=',<EQ>,1:26]
[@5,28:32=''123'',<StringLiteral>,1:28]
[@6,33:33=']',<']'>,1:33]
[@7,34:33='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:34]
```

Token rules will choose the longest match.

A comment on your grammar...

You probably want to make QUOTE a fragment, so that it can't be recognized as a toke on it's own (but only within Lexer rules where you reference it) (Any rule beginning with a Capital is a Lexer Rule (it's customary to make Lexer Rules all caps, but it's the first letter that "matters")

If I change the `QUOTE` rule to `fragment QUOTE: '\'';`

Then the tokenStream is: (including the error message again)

```
[@0,0:0='[',<'['>,1:0]
[@1,1:15='network-traffic',<IdentifierWithHyphen>,1:1]
[@2,16:16=':',<':'>,1:16]
[@3,17:24='src_port',<IdentifierWithoutHyphen>,1:17]
[@4,26:26='=',<EQ>,1:26]
[@5,28:28=''',<InvalidCharacter>,1:28]
[@6,29:31='123',<IntPosLiteral>,1:29]
[@7,32:32=']',<']'>,1:32]
[@8,33:32='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:33]
line 1:28 no viable alternative at input 'network-traffic:src_port=''
```

You get the same "no viable alternative" error, but you also get an `InvalidCharacter: .;` token that helps hint at the problem.

---

As to the question of why you get different results when there is a single alternative on the propTest rule...  That's rather interesting.  When have the single rule, then I get a `extraneous input ''' expecting {` warning on your example, and a `mismatched input ']' expecting {` warning on the second example in your comments.

Both of these are a result of ANTLR's attempts at better error recovery.  (See sections: "Recovering from Errors in SubRules" and "A Parade of Errors" in "The Definitve ANTLR 4 Refenence" from Pragmatic Programmers (pretty much a "must have" book if you are going to do much with ANTLR)).  It seems pretty obvious now, that when ANTLR has multiple rule alternatives, it can't really engage in these recovery attempts.  (I did look at the ATN graphs, but they don't really cover these error recovery paths, so the differences were "uninteresting")

Since you'd only see those warnings with the single alternative version of your propTest parser rule, dealing with them may actually be "beside the point".  Just go with the `no viable alternative` error you'll get for the erroneous input and move on.

FYI... if you want to pursue an option that does give use these error recovery strategies, but be made aware of these warnings, you can implement your own `ErrorListener` class.

I've pretty much always done this just so I was in more control of capturing all errors and warnings and deciding how to manage them in the UI.  The default ErrorHandler pretty much just spits messages out to the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. My confusion is as soon as I remove objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) objectPathThl    # propTestThlEqual then the match happens for this rule objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual but when both of them exists nothing will match and I have no clue whats going on

Comment: Ah.  Just tried with " | objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) objectPathThl    # propTestThlEqual" commented out.   It still gets an error "extraneous input ''' expecting {IntNegLiteral,", however it ignores the extraneous ' and basically treats the 123 as an IntPosLiteral alternative on the orderedLiteral parser rule.  Since the ignored ' occurs at exactly the same place in your rule as where the rule alternatives diverge, I suspect that having the alternatives impacts ANTLRs logic to attempt to match a rule by ignoring a token.  This is a bit "surprising", and I may take a deeper look.

Comment: I would suggest that you not ignore the extraneous input error/warning, since it still indicates that the input really didn't match your grammar.  I you treat it as an error, the only practical difference is what error is reported.

Comment: I suspect that generating the ATN *.dot files and perusing them might show the difference.   They can really shed light on how ANTLR evaluates your input.  I'll try to take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry if I am too beginner with antlre :). So how can I not ignore the extraneous input error/warning extraneous input error/warning? So my first issue is I need the same behaviour when there is only objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual compared to the case where we have this as well | objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) objectPathThl   # propTestThlEqual then for sure I will take care the errors in exit rules in js.The problem is as soon as the second one is added antlre totally ignore both rules and nothing exited in exitPropTestThlEqual and exitPropTestEqual

Comment: here is another example I tried and the same behaviour [ipv4-addr:value =]
as soon as I delete the second rule the first one gets triggered

Comment: I've added a section to my answer discussing why it appears that these differences appear, and how you might handle them.  I think the short answer, is that both of your input examples are actually syntactically invalid, and accepting the consistent "no viable alternative message" is the best way forward.  It is certainly interesting that the error recovery strategies are only triggered in the single alternative rules, but not entirely surprising.

Comment: You are awesome thank you. another check I was thinking to ask my users to intentionally inset NOT = instead of = and then this way I can work around this issue. Do you think it is a good idea?

Comment: I’d hate to see you have to take such an approach.  Maybe I’m missing something, but I didn’t see how the “NOT” factored into it.    The difference in behavior between a single alternative rule and a multiple alternative rule was interesting (made me go “hmmm” and look a bit deeper), but all the situations giving a “no viable alternative “ error were syntax errors, so I’m not seeing a problem (maybe I’m not paying close enough attention?)

Comment: You are right the only thing in the one rule situation it is guaranteed that the same behaviour will persist (think of release of a product) so this  [ipv4-addr:value =]  does not produce a different tree all of the sudden.

Comment: You’re always going to have situations where a syntax error fails to produce a tree with everything in it (well the contents are referencable from error nodes on the tree). Also, those single rule trees are tossing some input aside in an attempt to recover more gracefully (though still an error)