# grammar does not separate '123 and ] though the rule is set for it

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am new to antlr. I am trying to parse some queries like [network-traffic:src_port = '123] and [network-traffic:src_port =] and [network-traffic:src_port = ] and ... I have a grammar as follows:

```
grammar STIXPattern;

pattern
  : observationExpressions EOF
  ;

observationExpressions
  : <assoc=left> observationExpressions FOLLOWEDBY observationExpressions #observationExpressionsFollowedBY
  | observationExpressionOr                                               #observationExpressionOr_
  ;

observationExpressionOr
  : <assoc=left> observationExpressionOr OR observationExpressionOr     #observationExpressionOred
  | observationExpressionAnd                                            #observationExpressionAnd_
  ;

observationExpressionAnd
  : <assoc=left> observationExpressionAnd AND observationExpressionAnd  #observationExpressionAnded
  | observationExpression                                               #observationExpression_
  ;

observationExpression
  : LBRACK comparisonExpression RBRACK        # observationExpressionSimple
  | LPAREN observationExpressions RPAREN      # observationExpressionCompound
  | observationExpression startStopQualifier  # observationExpressionStartStop
  | observationExpression withinQualifier     # observationExpressionWithin
  | observationExpression repeatedQualifier   # observationExpressionRepeated
  ;

comparisonExpression
  : <assoc=left> comparisonExpression OR comparisonExpression         #comparisonExpressionOred
  | comparisonExpressionAnd                                           #comparisonExpressionAnd_
  ;

comparisonExpressionAnd
  : <assoc=left> comparisonExpressionAnd AND comparisonExpressionAnd  #comparisonExpressionAnded
  | propTest                                                          #comparisonExpressionAndpropTest
  ;

propTest
  : objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) primitiveLiteral       # propTestEqual
  | objectPath NOT? (GT|LT|GE|LE) orderableLiteral  # propTestOrder
  | objectPath NOT? IN setLiteral                   # propTestSet
  | objectPath NOT? LIKE StringLiteral              # propTestLike
  | objectPath NOT? MATCHES StringLiteral           # propTestRegex
  | objectPath NOT? ISSUBSET StringLiteral          # propTestIsSubset
  | objectPath NOT? ISSUPERSET StringLiteral        # propTestIsSuperset
  | LPAREN comparisonExpression RPAREN              # propTestParen
  | objectPath NOT? (EQ|NEQ) objectPathThl    # propTestThlEqual
  ;

startStopQualifier
  : START TimestampLiteral STOP TimestampLiteral
  ;

withinQualifier
  : WITHIN (IntPosLiteral|FloatPosLiteral) SECONDS
  ;

repeatedQualifier
  : REPEATS IntPosLiteral TIMES
  ;

objectPath
  : objectType COLON firstPathComponent objectPathComponent?
  ;

objectPathThl
  : varThlType DOT firstPathComponent objectPathComponent?
  ;

objectType
  : IdentifierWithoutHyphen
  | IdentifierWithHyphen
  ;

varThlType
  : IdentifierWithoutHyphen
  | IdentifierWithHyphen
  ;

firstPathComponent
  : IdentifierWithoutHyphen
  | StringLiteral
  ;

objectPathComponent
  : <assoc=left> objectPathComponent objectPathComponent  # pathStep
  | '.' (IdentifierWithoutHyphen | StringLiteral)         # keyPathStep
  | LBRACK (IntPosLiteral|IntNegLiteral|ASTERISK) RBRACK  # indexPathStep
  ;

setLiteral
  : LPAREN RPAREN
  | LPAREN primitiveLiteral (COMMA primitiveLiteral)* RPAREN
  ;

primitiveLiteral
  : orderableLiteral  
  | BoolLiteral  
  | edgeCases  
  ;

edgeCases
  : QUOTE (IdentifierWithHyphen | IdentifierWithoutHyphen | IntNoSign) RBRACK 
  | RBRACK
  ;


orderableLiteral
  : IntPosLiteral
  | IntNegLiteral
  | FloatPosLiteral
  | FloatNegLiteral
  | StringLiteral
  | BinaryLiteral
  | HexLiteral
  | TimestampLiteral
  ;



IntNegLiteral :
  '-' ('0' | [1-9] [0-9]*)
  ;

IntNoSign :
  ('0' | [1-9] [0-9]*)
  ;

IntPosLiteral :
  '+'? ('0' | [1-9] [0-9]*)
  ;

FloatNegLiteral :
  '-' [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
  ;

FloatPosLiteral :
  '+'? [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
  ;

HexLiteral :
  'h' QUOTE TwoHexDigits* QUOTE
  ;

BinaryLiteral :
  'b' QUOTE
  ( Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char )*
  ( (Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char )
  | (Base64Char Base64Char Base64Char ) '='
  | (Base64Char Base64Char ) '=='
  )
  QUOTE
  ;

StringLiteral :
  QUOTE ( ~['\\] | '\\\'' | '\\\\' )* QUOTE
  ;

BoolLiteral :
  TRUE | FALSE
  ;

TimestampLiteral :
  't' QUOTE
  [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] HYPHEN
  ( ('0' [1-9]) | ('1' [012]) ) HYPHEN
  ( ('0' [1-9]) | ([12] [0-9]) | ('3' [01]) )
  'T'
  ( ([01] [0-9]) | ('2' [0-3]) ) COLON
  [0-5] [0-9] COLON
  ([0-5] [0-9] | '60')
  (DOT [0-9]+)?
  'Z'
  QUOTE
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Keywords

AND:  'AND' ;
OR:  'OR' ;
NOT:  'NOT' ;
FOLLOWEDBY: 'FOLLOWEDBY';
LIKE:  'LIKE' ;
MATCHES:  'MATCHES' ;
ISSUPERSET:  'ISSUPERSET' ;
ISSUBSET: 'ISSUBSET' ;
LAST:  'LAST' ;
IN:  'IN' ;
START:  'START' ;
STOP:  'STOP' ;
SECONDS:  'SECONDS' ;
TRUE:  'true' ;
FALSE:  'false' ;
WITHIN:  'WITHIN' ;
REPEATS:  'REPEATS' ;
TIMES:  'TIMES' ;

// After keywords, so the lexer doesn't tokenize them as identifiers.
// Object types may have unquoted hyphens, but property names
// (in object paths) cannot.
IdentifierWithoutHyphen :
  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
  ;

IdentifierWithHyphen :
  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_-]*
  ;

EQ        :   '=' | '==';
NEQ       :   '!=' | '<>';
LT        :   '<';
LE        :   '<=';
GT        :   '>';
GE        :   '>=';

QUOTE     : '\'';
COLON     : ':' ;
DOT       : '.' ;
COMMA     : ',' ;
RPAREN    : ')' ;
LPAREN    : '(' ;
RBRACK    : ']' ;
LBRACK    : '[' ;
PLUS      : '+' ;
HYPHEN    : MINUS ;
MINUS     : '-' ;
POWER_OP  : '^' ;
DIVIDE    : '/' ;
ASTERISK  : '*';
EQRBRAC : ']';

fragment HexDigit: [A-Fa-f0-9];
fragment TwoHexDigits: HexDigit HexDigit;
fragment Base64Char: [A-Za-z0-9+/];

// Whitespace and comments
//
WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000B\u000C\u0085\u00a0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;

// Catch-all to prevent lexer from silently eating unusable characters.
InvalidCharacter
    : .
    ;
```

Now when I feed [network-traffic:src_port = '123] I expect antlr to parse the query to '123 and ]

However the grammar return '123] and is not able to separate '123 and ]
Am missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> grammar does not separate '123 and ] though the rule is set for it

That is not true. The quote and `123` *are* separate tokens. As demonstrated/suggested in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323946/antlr-does-not-match-the-pattens-properly-when-there-are-similar-patterns) ANTLR question: start by printing all the tokens to your console to see what tokens are being created. This should always be the first thing you do when trying to debug an ANTLR grammar. It will save you a lot of time and headache.

The fact `[network-traffic:src_port = '123]` is not parsed properly, is because the `]`(`RBRACK`) is being consumed by the alternative `observationExpressionSimple`:

```
observationExpression
  : LBRACK comparisonExpression RBRACK        # observationExpressionSimple
  | LPAREN observationExpressions RPAREN      # observationExpressionCompound
  | observationExpression startStopQualifier  # observationExpressionStartStop
  | observationExpression withinQualifier     # observationExpressionWithin
  | observationExpression repeatedQualifier   # observationExpressionRepeated
  ;
```

Because `RBRACK` was already consumed by a parser rule, the `edgeCases` rule can't consume this `RBRACK` token as well.

To fix this, change your rule:

```
edgeCases
  : QUOTE (IdentifierWithHyphen | IdentifierWithoutHyphen | IntNoSign) RBRACK
  | RBRACK
  ;
```

into this:

```
edgeCases
  : QUOTE (IdentifierWithHyphen | IdentifierWithoutHyphen | IntNoSign)
  ;
```

Now `[network-traffic:src_port = '123]` will be parsed properly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. Sorry I am too beginner in antlr and ask too much :)
in the secnd line I have  | RBRACK and my purpose was to match inputs like this [network-traffic:src_port = ] or [network-traffic:src_port =] or [network-traffic:src_port =    ] if I remove RBRACK there then how can I match the queries with these formats?

Comment: You could try making `edgeCases` optional then by adding a `?` after it where it's used. No idea if that is going to work OK in all cases for you, but letting `edgeCases` match `]` is not OK since that token is already consumed.

Comment: Thanks also may I have your opinion on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323946/antlr-does-not-match-the-pattens-properly-when-there-are-similar-patterns the answer concluded that there is a surprising behaviour in atlr as soon as the second rule is added but I am just checking in case you have different input on that